# Powershell: Export/Import DHCP scope

Tags: powershell, import, scope, export, dhcp

I need to export a dhcp scope from server A (include reservation and address lease) to server B.

To export from server A, I use the following command:

```
Export-DhcpServer -ComputerName A -ScopeId 10.20.30.40 -File .\Archives\scope.xml -Leases
```

But, on server B, there are others scopes in use and server B has DNS and Wins options configured on Server Options. The scope is imported with success, but the options scope overwrites the server options from server A.

To import on server B, I use the following command:

```
Import-DhcpServer -ComputerName B -File .\Archives\scope.xml -BackupPath .\Logs\dhcpbackup
```

How to export the scope from server A without server options ?

or

How to import this scope without server options on server B ?

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for [`Import-DhcpServer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/dhcpserver/import-dhcpserver?view=windowsserver2022-ps) states the following:

> If you specify either the ScopeId or the Prefix parameter, or both, only the specified scopes or prefixes are imported.
>
> If you specify neither the ScopeId nor the Prefix parameter, all of the configurations that is contained in the file, and optionally any lease data, is imported.
>
> If you specify the Leases parameter, the lease data in the specified file is imported in addition to configuration data.

So if you include `ScopeId` and/or `Prefix` parameters it shouldn't overwrite.

For [`Export-DhcpServer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/dhcpserver/export-dhcpserver?view=windowsserver2022-ps):

> If you specify the ScopeId or Prefix parameter,only the specified scopes or prefixes and all server level settings are exported.
>
> If you specify neither ScopeId or Prefix, the DHCP server service configuration including all scopes, v4 and v6 and optionally the lease data, is exported.